# How to connect a 12V battery to a 24V system?

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, 12v, 24v

I have a 24V battery (two 12V lead/acid in series) connected to solar panels and I'm looking for a way to have a 12V battery and circuit. (But the solar array will charge the 24V system so i need the 12V battery to be charged with power from the 24V)

I bought :
- A 12V battery
- A Step-down 24V to 12V converter 30 Amps

Can I simply connect the 24V to 12V converter to the 24V battery and connect just after it the 12V battery? Or do I need something else, like a battery charge controller?

Comment: How does your step down converter feel about having a battery connected to its output?

Comment: If 12V is what you need, why can't you use the step down converter directly, without the 12V battery?

Comment: @winny that's part of what my question is about, do they have a current backward protection or something else ?

Comment: @Dampmaskin Well at some point i might have to recharge this 12V battery with another system. (maybe wind power). Furthermore, i would like to have an inverter that could use more than 30A. (12v)

Comment: Please make your question clear. What is the output of your solar panel? If its output is 12V (as usual), then you need to change the battery's connection to become parallel (double the current capacity but lower voltage with power will remain same as P=V*I). If its output is 24V, then your connection is correct, you then just need to connect the panel output to the battery. So, make your question firs clear. Make schematic, so you will get the right answer.

Comment: ANY time you define a PS spec. Include current

Comment: The more information you give the better the answer. Battery ratings (ideally brand and model). Use of 12V - initial and later. You say - I ... inverter 12V > 30a. -> Why? IF you have 24V then it's better to use 24V x 15A than 12V x 30A unless there is a good reason not to. |A full picture will help us help you. || As is an inverter straight into 12V may overload the inverter in some cases and overcharge the battery in others. A cheap 12V charger or "solar" controller may be useful.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I had a 12V system before and already have an "expensive" Viktron inverter 12V. I wish to be able to use it... So.. are you saying that i can simply put a PWM (i have an old one) just after the Step-down 24->12 and plug it on the 12V battery ?

Comment: @bobdylan Having an inverter already may well qualify as "a good reason" :-) || A PWM controller usually takes a voltage somewhat more than 12V and uses it to "properly charge a 12V battery. Hopefully the 24->12V inverter can have its Vout adjusted somewhat. If so, setting it (if possible) to 15 to 16V and feeding it into the PWM controller should work. If you cannot do this then a fixed 12V output will sort of charge a 12V lead acid battery but not properly. Worst case you MAY get more current than the 12V battery needs at low battery SOC but not enough voltage to charge it fully or well.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I don't think i can tweak the steady 12V but would it be better to use instead a "battery charge controller" like the XY-L30A ?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon put it just after the 24>12 of course.

Comment: My battery 12V is AGM deep cycle.

Comment: @bobdylan The objct of adding the PWM controller is to (1) Limit the end of charge conditions correctly, to stop the battery "cooking". (2) Limit current into the battery when required (to stop it "cooking")  . || 12V is NOT a suitable voltage for charging a "12V" lead acid battery - AGM or any other.  - The battery MUST be held at above about 12.6V whenever possible or it will sulphate. - During bulk charing the voltage will rise to ABOUT 13.6V - During absorption charge (brieflyish) the voltage will rise to about 14.4V. A "proper" charger looks after these factors.

Comment: @RussellMcMahonI see thanks for the details. Do you know if something like a XY-L30A (Images : https://duckduckgo.com/?q=XY-L30A&t=canonical&ia=images&iax=images) can do that from a steady 12V ?

Comment: I don't think so... but i don't know what equipment I need. All the "chargers" i can find are all AC to 12V dc...

Comment: I had an idea... Can I just plug the PWM to the 24v battery as input and let it charge the 12v battery ?